# How to target an individual icon from rest of the other icons?

Tags: jquery, css, font-awesome, accordion

I have a list of accordions, and each of the accordions expands (+) and collapses(-) when you click on it.  Problem is, when I try to expand one of the accordion tabs, it expands and collapses fine, but the icons '-'/'+' sign toggles for all the other accordions as well even if they haven't been clicked on. I want the '-'/'+' icon to toggle only for the accordion that I clicked on, not for the other accordions.

```
cshtml:
<h2 class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#anyId" name=""><button>@l.GetElementValue("Title")</button></h2>

 <div id="anyId" class="collapse">
    @foreach ())
   {
     // looping through accordion list. 
   }
  </div>



CSS:
.accordion-toggle:after {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome'; /* essential to enable caret symbol*/
    content: "\f068"; /* adjust as needed, taken from font-awesome.css */
    color: #0046ad;
    position: absolute;
    left: .5em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -12px;
    font-size: 25px;

}

.accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
    /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
    /*font-family: 'FontAwesome';*/
    content: "\f067"; /* adjust as needed, taken from font-awesome.css */
    /*color: #0046ad;
    position: absolute;
    left: .5em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -12px;
    font-size: 25px;*/
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the generated HTML and any relevant JS?

Comment: please edit your question instead of pasting in comments

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question and include a [mcve] to your question for faster, better answers

Comment: Hi, I guess my general question is, how can I set an individual icon for an accordion, instead of have the icon as a shared for all the accordions?

Comment: @Cliff you may need to supply a working snippet via js fiddle or stackblitz. At a glance it looks like you are using a plugin. I would have thought your issue would be due to a shared selector between each item but without a working example it's hard to tell.

Comment: You will need to target the clicked element only then change its icon; Using JavaScript you can use "this" to target the clicked element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove by default collapsed class and use below css.

```
.accordion-toggle:after {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome'; /* essential to enable caret symbol*/
    content: "\f067";
    position: absolute;
    left: .5em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -12px;
    font-size: 25px;*/
}

.collapsed:after {
    content: "\f068";
}
```

Please refer below link that I used your structure here. Ignore js just try css,

https://jsfiddle.net/jignashagpatel/rmpnaq59/7/

Comment: Thank you @jignasha for your help on this. This is working now.

Comment: Hi @jignasha, I have a follow up question. Instead of using Font Awesome unicodes such as f067, f068, I was wondering is there a way to directly use font awesome classes such as (<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>)  in the CSS or in the JS?